# Ruby Marshal::Load 1.8.1 File From 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, version, unmarshalling

Is it possible to `Marshal::load` a file that was dumped with ruby version 1.8.1 from ruby 1.9.3?

Answer (score 2):

It should work (I don't have 1.8.1 installed to explicitly test it). Per [the Marshal documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Marshal.html):

> Marshaled data has major and minor version numbers stored along with the object information. In normal use, marshaling can only load data written with the same major version number and an equal or lower minor version number. If Ruby’s “verbose” flag is set (normally using -d, -v, -w, or –verbose) the major and minor numbers must match exactly. Marshal versioning is independent of Ruby’s version numbers. You can extract the version by reading the first two bytes of marshaled data.

As of Ruby 1.9.3, `marshall.c` defines the major/minor versions as:

```
#define MARSHAL_MAJOR   4
#define MARSHAL_MINOR   8
```

Looking at Ruby 1.8.1's `marshall.c` shows the same versions.

Comment: oh I guess I'm not looking at ruby Marshalled data then. its RPG maker vx data files  and they look similar. I tried loading them with 1.9.3 but it said wrong version. oh well, I guess I will have to reverse engineer it. I'm not by a computer at present but I will take your word for it. thanks!

Comment: Hmm I have now tried dumping regular data from ruby 1.8.1 but 1.9.3 cant load it - should I un-accept this answer and update question? (Sorry to be a pain)

Comment: were there any error messages? Like missing class dependecies?